# Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Client.Feature.Membership.Services.FacetUpdaters.IContactFacetUpdater]'

Tags: habitat, dependency-injection, federated-authentication

I'm trying to replicate the federated auth from habitat using the Facebook example, and parlay that into auth with Salesforce. I can't get around this dependency injection error though.

Starting with the stack trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Client.Feature.Membership.Services.FacetUpdaters.IContactFacetUpdater]' while attempting to activate 'Client.Feature.Membership.Services.UpdateContactFacetsService'.]
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound) +443
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain) +396
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain) +172
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain) +78
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain) +157
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound) +109
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain) +396
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain) +172
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain) +78
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain) +157
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound) +109
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain) +396
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain) +172
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain) +78
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain) +157
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType) +97
   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +88
   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope) +46
   Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreDependencyResolver.GetService(Type serviceType) +41
   Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreControllerFactory.ResolveController(Type type) +46
   Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +95

[ControllerCreationException: Could not create controller: 'Client.Feature.Membership.Controllers.MembershipController, Client.Feature.Membership'. 
The context item is: '/sitecore/content/Client/Home/Sample'. 
The current route url is: '{*pathInfo}'. This is the default Sitecore route which is set up in the 'InitializeRoutes' processor of the 'initialize' pipeline. ]
   Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +171
   Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.GetController() +23
   Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.Execute(TextWriter writer) +39
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args) +74
   (Object , Object ) +14
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +490
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args) +192
   (Object , Object ) +14
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +490
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.RenderPlaceholderCore(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer) +250
   Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName) +61
   ASP._Page_Views_Navigation_Header_cshtml.Execute() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Client.dev.local\Views\Navigation\Header.cshtml:42
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +252
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +148
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +378
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +91
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +795
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +795
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +81
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +698
```

The class in question:

```
[Service(typeof(IUpdateContactFacetsService))]
public class UpdateContactFacetsService : IUpdateContactFacetsService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The XDB context factory.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly IXdbContextFactory _xdbContextFactory;

    /// <summary>
    /// The contact manager.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly IContactManagerService _contactManager;

    /// <summary>
    /// The facet updaters.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly IList<IContactFacetUpdater> _facetUpdaters;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="UpdateContactFacetsService"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xdbContextFactory">The XDB context factory.</param>
    /// <param name="contactManager">The contact manager.</param>
    /// <param name="facetUpdaters">The facet updaters.</param>
    public UpdateContactFacetsService(IXdbContextFactory xdbContextFactory, IContactManagerService contactManager, IList<IContactFacetUpdater> facetUpdaters)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(xdbContextFactory, nameof(xdbContextFactory));
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(contactManager, nameof(contactManager));
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(facetUpdaters, nameof(facetUpdaters));
        Assert.ArgumentCondition(facetUpdaters.Any(), nameof(facetUpdaters), $"{nameof(facetUpdaters)} must not be empty");
        _xdbContextFactory = xdbContextFactory;
        _contactManager = contactManager;
        _facetUpdaters = facetUpdaters;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed a few things and can no longer replicate the error. Most likely candidates:

1) Associated the site to the identity provider:

```
<sitecore>
    <federatedAuthentication>
      <identityProvidersPerSites>
        <mapEntry name="ClientSitecom" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
          <sites hint="list">
            <site>ClientSitecom</site>
          </sites>
          <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
            <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='Facebook']"/>
          </identityProviders>
          <externalUserBuilder type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultExternalUserBuilder, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
            <param desc="isPersistentUser">true</param>
          </externalUserBuilder>
        </mapEntry>
      </identityProvidersPerSites>
    </federatedAuthentication>
    <sites>
```

2) ensure the ServiceRegistration in the Account feature was populating the correct  properties of IContactFacetUpdater